# Excel: Sum based on criteria (SUMIF)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I'm trying to do a sum in an Excel table, but I can't figure out how to do it.

The table should look like this with the last column (Remaining) counting down the remaining budget:

```
      A        B         C        D

1     Project  Budget    Costs    Remaining 
      -------------------------------------
2     A        110.000   10.000   100.000
3     B        25.000    100      24.900
4     A        110.000   12.000   88.000
5     A        110.000   1.000    87.000
6     B        25.000    1.000    23.900
```

I really hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula in cell D2, and copied down:

```
=B2-SUMIF(A$2:A2,A2,C$2:C2)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work CFO. It should also subtract values for Project B

Comment: Using that formula I replicated your illustration.  Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: The goal is to show the remaining budget for each project (there are around 30 projects). Each project has its own budget and on every row in the table, someone can fill in the costs and it should show the remaining budget per Project. I hope this clarifies it more.

Comment: Got it.  I still think my formula works.  It looks at the project reference in column A, uses the project total for it in column B and then subtracts any costs for that specific project in column C